# Get Bounds Of Appended UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibezierpath, bounds

So I have a `UIBezierPath` with multiple appended paths, now, I want to access the bounds of every appended paths in that `UIBezierPath`, is there a way I can have access to each of the appended `UIBezierPath` to the current `UIBezierPath` so I can get their bounds? I've been searching but can't find a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the bounding box over the underlying `CGPath`:

```
UIBezierPath thePath = ...;
CGRect theRect = CGPathGetBoundingBox(thePath.CGPath);
```

EDIT: You can get each element of the path with [CGPathApply](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1411203-cgpathapply?language=objc). The callback is called with a `CGPathElement` for each element of the path, by which you can reconstruct the original path element.

Comment: but it only returns the overall bounds of the uibezierpath itself but not the bounds of every appended path to that uibezierpath :(

Comment: Do you know a way so I can access the appended paths from the current uibezierpath?

Comment: I've been considering CGPathApply too but it's too much of a process just to get the bounds.. isn't there any other easier way?

Comment: `CGPathApply` is the only way to access the elements of a path. What do you mean with appended path? You can calculate the bounds when you append a path.

Comment: Yeah the bounds I need is the bounds of the path that was appended, not the uibezierpath's bounds where the path was appended...

Comment: You can create a new path object from the parts you will append, calculate its bounds and than append it to the entire path.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much for the idea, I appreciated it. Thanks @macmoonshine